# Como guardo un string en un arreglo char en c++?

Tags: array

mi problema parte en que capturo 2 strings y luego quiero guardarlos en sus arreglos

```
string nombre_buscado;
string apellido_buscado;
```

a

```
nombre[5][10]
apellido[5][10]
```

y me da el error en:

```
nombre[i]=nombre_buscado;
apellido[i]=apellido_buscado;
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Agrega tu código para poder ayudarte, así como tienes tu pregunta es muy amplia. También puedes revisar [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo veo es que nombre[i]=nombre_buscado te hace falta la ubicación esto quedaría así:
nombre[i]=nombre_buscado[i] y esto va dentro de un for para que pases todas las ubicaciones.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string mensaje, otroMensaje[10];
int i;

mensaje = "Pedrito";
for(i=0;i<7; i++){
    otroMensaje[i] = mensaje[i];
}

cout << endl;
for(i=0;i<7; i++){
    cout << otroMensaje[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entonces para mi arreglo bidimensional, seria exactamente asi?

Comment: no se para que quieras un arreglo bidimencional en todo caso usa uno unidimencional pero si quieres bidimencional puedes usar dos for para que recorra las dos dimenciones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que estas creando arreglos bidimencionales, por lo que para guardar valores en ellos, tienes que indicar las posiciones donde lo almacenaras.

```
nombre[5][10]
```

`nombre` es un arreglo bidimencional de 5 filas y 10 columnas, si quieres almacenar un valor en ese arreglo tienes que indicar la posicion de la fila y de la columna donde se almacenara el valor.

```
nombre[2][5] = nombre_buscado;
```

En este caso, el valor de la variable `nombre_buscando` se almacenara en la fila 3 y en la columna 4. En los arreglos las posiciones se comienzan a contar desde cero. Si tienes un arreglo de 3 posiciones, la posiciones seran: 0, 1 y 2.